# Php :change timezone based on user

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to display the timezone based on the user visiting my website? I built a comment box and I want the displayed comments to show the time and date, which I've set up, but I would like the user to be able to see comments' time info to be adjusted automatically for the timezone of the user, so I'd see a different timestamp than someone in another area would see.

I tried searching this, but I keep seeing questions where people are asking about how to choose a specific timezone, which isn't what I want. Sorry if I made a duplicate question.

Currently I'm displaying the date and time by using this code:

```
<?php echo datetime_to_text($comment_text["created"]); ?>
```

The function it's using is:

```
function datetime_to_text($datetime="") {
$unixdatetime = strtotime($datetime);
return strftime("%B %d, %Y", $unixdatetime);
}
```

I think my database is currently storing this info in the UTC timezone by default. I don't know if this is relevant, but I also saw other questions referring to the php.ini file, but my server won't let me access it or upload my own.

The answer doesn't need to be in php, if something is easier, I've just never used javascript and I wrote the comment box code with php, so I just default to it.

Answer (score 0):

In php you only have the possibility to use a DB like [GeoIP of Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/) that *maps* IP to geolocation. While IP addresses do not carry any information about the real location, as someone could use his IP address all over the world using VPN or use a Proxy, TOR network,  to just name some situation where IP address is not reliable. But many people get their IP of their ISP and don't use any of those tools.
This information is collected by those DBs. So depending on what you want to achieve this guesses could be accurate enough for you.

Another possibility would be to `geolocation` of browsers (a *relatively* new feature) to ask for the location, the user needs to confirm that you want to have this information and then you could pass it to your server to store the geo information in a session.